# docker-compose dns and python docker api nested container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, python-docker

The `cis` container is running a simple flask server that calls `daemon()` on the backend. As part of the nested container's functionality, it needs to be able to access the `git` container as well as other infrastructure on the network.

In the current setup, all services are accessible to each other by hostname, and they are accessible to the other machines on the network, also by hostname. However, the nested container is unable to resolve hostnames.

What can I do so that the nested container is able to resolve the necessary hostnames?

```
def daemon(dc:DockerClient,
           url:str, image:str)->Tuple[str,int]:
    try:
        cont = dc.containers.create(image,
                                    #network='myproject_default',
                                    network='ops')
        try:
            cont.start()
            status = cont.wait()['StatusCode']
            logs = cont.logs().decode('utf-8')
            return logs, status
        finally:
            cont.remove()        
    except errors.APIError:
        raise
    except Exception:
        raise
```

Sample `docker-compose` config:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  git:
    image: rockstorm/git-server
    hostname:        git.mynetwork.com
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:myport1:myport1/tcp"
    networks:
      - default
      - ops

  cis:
    image: cis
    hostname:                 cis.mynetwork.com
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:myport2:myport2/tcp"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
    networks:
      - default
      - ops
    depends_on:
      git:
        condition:   service_started
```

in `/etc/hosts`:

```
myip           git                 git.innovanon.com
myip           cis                 cis.innovanon.com
```

Comment: You'd need to know the Docker name of the Compose network.  The commented-out `myproject_default` is a likely candidate, but it will depend on the current directory name and the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable normally.  Make sure you are using the short names like `git` and `cis`.

Comment: I overlooked that I have a port mapping on the git server. Using the internal port 22 works. Your comment helped me realize that it wasn't a DNS issue after all.